# Item Quantity Discount

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ItemDiscount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 5;
        final int DISCOUNT1 = 1-12;
        final int DISCOUNT2 = 13-49;
        final int DISCOUNT3 = 50-99;
        final int DISCOUNT4 = 100-199;
        final int DISCOUNT5 = 200;
        int [] Purchased_Item = {DISCOUNT1, DISCOUNT2, DISCOUNT3, DISCOUNT4, DISCOUNT5};
        double [] Discount = {0.00, 0.10, 0.14, 0.18, 0.20};
        
        double ItemDiscount = 0;
        int Item1 = 0;
        boolean Item = false;
        
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of item/s you purchased: ");
        int num_of_item = input.nextInt();
        
        for (int x = 0; x < b; x++){
            if (Item1 == Purchased_Item[x]){
                Item = true;
                ItemDiscount = Discount[x];
            }
        }
        
        if (Item)
            System.out.println("No Discount");
        else
            System.out.println("The discount of " + num_of_item +" items is " + ItemDiscount);
    }
}
```

This is the code that I've been working on. You insert the number of items that you will purchase and the system should give an output if you have a discount.

This is a program that allows the user to enter the number of items and checks the discounts.
[This is the guide table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lue9m.png)

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTxDT.png)

The output I've been getting keeps giving me 0.0 or 0% discount when I input any number. Thought it should say that when you enter 200 and above you should have a discount of 0.20 or 20%.

Please give me suggestions and teach me what I should be doing. Thank you

Comment: Just to make sure, you do know that `final int DISCOUNT1 = 1-12;` doesn't represent a range from 1 to 12, but -11 instead?

Comment: Regarding your issue: Where do you store the user input, in which variable? And where do you use that variable? Shouldn't you use it on other places as well?

Comment: There is so much wrong stuff going on in that code..

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally choose a different data structure to hold the discount levels - for example a `LinkedHashMap`, which in layman's terms is a `HashMap` that stays in the order that you create it. Storing 2 sets of values separately even though they are obviously linked to one another is not a good idea. Then make a method that returns the correct discount level based on the amount of purchased items. Let's call this class `Discount.class`:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Discount {

    private Map<Integer, Double> discountMap;

    public Discount() {
        discountMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>();
        discountMap.put(0, 0.00d);
        discountMap.put(12, 0.10d);
        discountMap.put(49, 0.14d);
        discountMap.put(99, 0.18d);
        discountMap.put(199, 0.20d);
    }

    public Double getDiscountAmount(int amountPurchased) {
        Double currentDiscount = 0.00d;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : discountMap.entrySet()) {
            if (amountPurchased > entry.getKey()) {
                currentDiscount = entry.getValue();
            } else {
                return currentDiscount;
            }
        }
        return currentDiscount;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this class in your program to get the level of discount that you should apply

```
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number of item/s you purchased: ");
int numberOfItems = input.nextInt();

Discount discount = new Discount();
Double discountAmount = discount.getDiscountAmount(numberOfItems);

System.out.printf("The discount of %s items is %s%%",
            numberOfItems,
            Math.round(discountAmount*100));
```

There are more "slicker" solutions to this problem, the way this solution is written is just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Is there a simpler way on how this can be made without using `LinkedHashMap`? I'm thinking of using just an array and scanner.

Comment: Well you need to hold the information about "how many purchases correspond to what discount". That's not one, but two values to hold for each "level" of discount. You'd need two arrays for this, as you did in your example, but this is a very bad practice since once one of the arrays get's changed, i.e. something gets added to it or removed the two arrays won't work together. That's why it's preferred to keep it in a single data structure such as a Map. Yes, you can do it with arrays, but no, it's not a good idea.

Comment: You could keep both of the values as a concatenated string in a single array and then split it as you'd iterate the array, but that is VERY sketchy.